# How to avoid cd to a directory without access permission

Tags: linux, bash, unix, csh

I have an array variable tht contains all directories in a folder.
 I need to cd to each directory in the $array. bt when it reach to a non accessible directory  , program halts . how can I avoid this so that my loop simply go to the next directory. code is

```
foreach dir ($array) 
  cd $dir
  echo "directory is $dir" 
cd - end
```

please help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just test that the cd worked.

```
( if cd $dir 2> /dev/null; then
   echo in directory $dir
   # Do other things
fi )
```

Also, note the parentheses.  These cause the entire clause to run in a subshell, so there's no need to cd back to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

If iam not mistaken you can use something like

```
if [ -r ${dir} ]
then
  echo "Have read access!"
fi
```

You can use `-w` for testing write access and `-x` for testing for the exceution bit.

Comment: this will echo the message only if owner of the file has read permissions but I want to check it for group read permission. how can that be done ?